# Facebook Graph API unable to get User friends Location

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am trying to retrieve & print User's friends locations. I am using following code:

```
{scope:'email,friends_location, user_location,publish_stream'});

results += '<div><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id +     '/picture">' + friend_data[i].name + friend_data[i].location + '</div>';
```

When I am printing value of `friend_data[i].location`, it print undefined, when I change this variable to `friend_data[i].location.name` then it doesn't work and nothing prints out of it. In User own location I am doing resource.location.name and it work fine.

I have searched many places and tried my code with various combinations but didn't work. 
Can anyone give me where I am wrong in this code?

Will be very much thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searched few other places, I am answering my own questions, might be helpful for someone in future. Actually I had set correct scope in my question. Probably I wasn't printing the output correctly. But below code definitely works.

Note: location here in the below query refers to current Location.

```
  $userFriend_profile = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=name,location&limit=20');


  $total = count($userFriend_profile['data']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total;)
    {
      if(isset($userFriend_profile['data'][$i]['location']['name']))
    {
    $city_Value = explode(',',trim($userFriend_profile['data'][$i]['location']['name']));

  }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all well and good to just write all the necessary permissions:

```
{scope:'email,friends_location, user_location,publish_stream'});
```

... but what for?

An access token is generated from the permissions you asked. When building the `graph.facebook.com` URL corresponding to your Graph query, you don't actually pass any access token. So, your permissions are unused, whatever you did with them before.

#### To do:

1. List the permissions (done),
2. Generate the access token from the permissions (done?),
3. Pass the access token to your Graph call.